# How to write the query that returns records where some column value appears more than once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table that has column with statuses. I need to write the query that returns records where some column value appears more than once?

Something like this:

```
select * from Table1
where COUNT(StatusID = 6) > 1
```

Comment: This makes no sense. A column appears only once per record of course. So what do you actually want? All rows that have a status that appears more than just once in the table? All rows of status 6, provided there exists more than one entry for status 6 in the table? Or are there several status columns per row?

Comment: The value of 6 can appear more than once in StatusID column. I need to obtain all records match that condition.

Comment: And what is the condition? That not only one record in the table has status 6? Or only that the record itself has status 6? Or what else?

Comment: The condition is - obtain all records where the value of 6 appears more than once in StatusID column.

Comment: Status 6 either appears 0, 1 or more times in the table. This is true for *every* record. It is about the table and has nothing to do with a record. So I suppose you want to say: Select all records with status 6 provided there are at least two records with status 6 in the table? Is this what you want?

Comment: Or are you saying that the status field contains a string like '1,1,2,6,6' and you want those where 6 appears more than once in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your query like following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE StatusID IN 
(
     SELECT StatusID
     FROM (SELECT StatusID,Count(*) AS cnt FROM Table1 WHERE StatusID=6 
     GROUP BY StatusID      
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS tbl
)
```